# Unable to Install Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 and unable to update Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

This is what  appears when I try `sudo apt-get update`:

[image: This is what appears when I try sudo apt-get update]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal text. Instead paste the text itself into your question, select it, and press the **{}** button in the editor to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I faced this issue on my system, I did an extensive search on Google. Post some good research, I figured out that `google-chrome-stable` is available via a [3rd party repository link.](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable)

Installation can be completed in just 3 steps as follows:

- Add the key using;

`wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -`

- Set the repository:

`echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

- Perform the final update & installation using the commands:

`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

This worked for me even on v16.04 LTS, so I am hopeful that it should work for you as well.

Comment: I am glad @shreyateeza that it worked for you too. Kindly upvote it so that others facing the same issue can benefit from it.

Also, do try updating Ubuntu now. If it works, great else we will figure out a solution for it too.

Comment: I am afraid I can't I tried to upvote but it isn't happening. :(

Comment: its ok @shreyateeza. It is because you do not have enough credits as of now. 
You marking the solution as right is enough right now for others to understand. 

Happy learning

Comment: I followed the above instruction, not working for me :(
::I got the msg ->>>>
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[16023:16057:1003/131242.663579:FATAL:nss_util.cc(655)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.

Comment: Hello @AnuragSrivastava which version of Ubuntu are you using on your system, I have tried these steps on v14 and also on v16.04 LTS and after you commented, I uninstalled google-chrome and reinstalled using the same steps and it worked fine for me. 
See if there is any other factor blocking your installation process. 
Let us know if there is any.

Comment: You legend, thank you!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @DmitryKamenetsky 
Glad you found it useful.